# effective_cache_size vs shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql, shared-buffers

What is the difference between effective_cache_size and shared_buffers ?
I got confused .While we trying to query on a table (like select) what happens to query? what role do the effective_cache_size and shared_buffers playing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two parameters are unrelated.

`shared_buffers` is the size of shared buffers, the shared memory segment that is allocated when PostgreSQL starts and caches all data that are read from or written to tables, indexes etc.

`effective_cache_size` is a parameter where you tell the optimizer how much RAM is available for caching PostgreSQL data (that is, shared buffers + any "unused" RAM in the machine). It is used to estimate the cost of index scans.